# Question about Total Probability problem

Tags: probability

I am stuck in a probability problem

Among a group of patients, it is found that 22% visit both a therapist and a chiropractor, 12% visit neither of these.
The probability that a patient visits a chiropractor exceeds by 14% the probability that a patient visits a physical therapist.

Determine the probability that a randomly chosen member of this group visits a physical therapist?

So, what we know:
$P(T \cap C) = 0.22$.

$P(T^C \cap C^C) = 0.22$. $P(C)=1.14P(T)$.
We are looking for $P(T)$.

I tried to use the total probability formula: 
$P(T) = P(T \cap C) + P(T \cap C^C)$.

$P(T) = 0.22 + P(C^C) P(T / C^C)$.

$P(T) = 0.22 + (1-P(C)) P(T / C^C)$.

$P(T) = 0.22 + (1-1.14P(T)) P(T / C^C)$.

But here I am stuck, because I don't know how to link the given information of $P(T^C \cap C^C) = 0.22$ to $P(T / C^C)$.

I know the result is $P(T) = 0.48$.

Can anyone help please?
Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing a Venn diagram makes this much easier.

We are given:
$$
\begin{align}
P(T \cap C) &= 0.22\\
P(\bar{T} \cap \bar{C}) &= 0.12
\end{align}
$$
The second of these tells us that $P(T \cup C) = .88$ since they are disjoint and between the two span the entire probability space. Now (and a Venn diagram helps with this):
$$
\begin{align}
P(T \cup C) &= P(T \cap \bar{C}) + P(\bar{T} \cap C) + P(T \cap C)\\
0.88 &= P(T \cap \bar{C}) + P(\bar{T} \cap C) + 0.22\\
0.66 &= P(T \cap \bar{C}) + P(\bar{T} \cap C)
\end{align}
$$

We were given $P(C) - P(T) = .14$ so:
$$
\begin{align}
P(T) &= P(T \cap C) + P(T \cap \bar{C})\\
P(C) &= P(T \cap C) + P(\bar{T} \cap C)\\
P(C) - P(T) &= \left(P(T \cap C) + P(\bar{T} \cap C)\right) - \left(P(T \cap C) + P(T \cap \bar{C})\right)\\
P(C) - P(T) &= P(\bar{T} \cap C) - P(T \cap \bar{C})
\end{align}
$$

So now we know that $P(\bar{T} \cap C) - P(T \cap \bar{C}) = 0.14$ so:
$$
\begin{align}
P(\bar{T} \cap C) + P(T \cap \bar{C}) &= 0.66\\
P(\bar{T} \cap C) - P(T \cap \bar{C}) &= 0.14\\
2P(\bar{T} \cap C)&= .8\\
P(\bar{T} \cap C)&= .4\\
P(T \cap \bar{C})&= .26\\
P(T) = P(T \cap \bar{C})+P(T \cap C) = .26+.22&=\mathbf{.48}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Avraham, so brilliant !

Comment: Thanks to Ross, for his contribution too.

Answer (score 1):

You have a Venn diagram with four regions, $N,T,C,TC$ where $TC$ is the population that visits both, $N$ the population that visits neither, etc.  We are told $$TC=22\%\\ N=12\%\\ TC+C=TC+T+14\%\\ N+T+C+TC=100\%$$  Four equations, four unknowns.

Comment: Yes, but in this case, we do not use the fact that the probability that a patient visits a chiropractor exceeds by 14% the probability that a patient visits a physical therapist.

Comment: I have to admit that I don't understand the 3rd line in your equation.

Comment: TC+C is all the people who visit the chiropractor, whether or not they visit the therapist.  Similarly TC+T is all the people who visit the therapist.  The 12 was a typo for 14.  We do need that data point.